# SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" in .NET 4.0 (not working with german .NET 4.0 Framework)

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, spell-checking

I have an WPF App, where I enabled the Spell-Checker for some TextBoxes.
When I run it locally it works well, but not when I run it at my clients site, on Win. XP PCs with .NET 4.0 (German) installed.

Actually It should access the German language dictionary, so I really not get the point.

Somehow I must have missed something. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual solution was to load the corresponding language pack extra from the microsoft website and install it.
I got wrong information from my client, language packs were not installed additionaly yet.